# using "this" inside function - nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, scope

I'm trying to create a class in node.js for a small project of mine but I can't really figure out how scoping works.

I have a basic constructor function:

```
function testClass(username){
this.config = {
    uName : username,
    url : 'url_prefix'+username,
};

this.lastGame = {
    firstTime : 1,
    time : null,
    outcome: null,
    playingAs: null,
    playingAgainst : null,
    };

this.loadProfile(this.config['url']);
};
```

And the loadProfile function:

```
testClass.prototype.loadProfile = function(url){

    request(url,function(error,response,body){

        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        matchTable = $('div[class=test]').children();
        tempLast = matchTable.first().html();

        if(this.config['firstTime'] == 1 || this.lastGame['time'] != tempLast){
            this.lastGame['time'] = tempLast;
        }


    });
};
```

(I'm using the Request and Cheerio libraries.)

The problem I have is that I can't use the class variables using "this" inside the "request" function.
It returns "Cannot read property 'firstTime' of Undefined".
This only happens inside the "request" function. I can use "this" and all its functions/variables just fine outside it.
I've thought about passing it to the function but a) I couldn't find how and b) That would mean that any modification I made to the variables wouldn't change the actual class variables.
Could anyone please explain what is going on?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution is to copy `this` into another variable called `self`.

However, if you aren't going to be creating very many instances of your "class", or it only has a few methods, then it's generally simpler to avoid using constructor functions, `this` and `new` altogether.

```
function makeAnObject(username){

    // declare private information:
    var url = 'url_prefix' + username;

    // return public information (usually functions):
    return {
        loadProfile: function(blah) {
            // ...
        }
    };
};
```

This lets you have genuinely private data, and you don't have to copy the parameters of `makeOnObject` by hand, and you don't have to worry about `this` being broken, or remember to prefix calls with `new`, etc.

Comment: I decided to do it this way as a learning exercise but I see what you mean. If I use your method, I declare all functions and variables that are meant to be used internally outside of the "return" block and everything that is meant to be used by each instance inside the block, right? How would I go about calling a function from each instance? (ie the equivalent of test.loadfunction() where test is the instance).

Comment: It would be the same. In JavaScript there are no classes, only objects. `test.loadfunction()` literally means the same as `test["loadfunction"]()` - in other words: assume variable `test` refers to an object, get the value of a property called `loadfunction` from that object, assume that value to be a function and call it with no arguments. (As an added wrinkle, it also sets `this` to refer to `test` inside the function call).

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll see how much of a fuss using what I currently have is and if it's too much I'll just switch to this solution. Thanks.

Comment: NB. There can be advantages to using `this`/`new`/constructors where you are going to be creating lots of instances with the same large number of methods, because by defining the methods once on the prototype and then sharing that prototype between all the instances you save some storage and speed up creation time. But it's best treated as an optimisation, not something you'd do for fun.

Answer (score 1):

Every `function` creates a new scope, since scopes are function-centric in JavaScript. The [ES6 `let` keyword](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/ecmascript-6-today/) will help you circumvent this kind of scenario. Before that, you'll have to stick to retaining a reference to the `this` you mean to use.

```
testClass.prototype.loadProfile = function(url){
    var self = this;

    request(url,function(error,response,body){

        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        matchTable = $('div[class=test]').children();
        tempLast = matchTable.first().html();

        if(self.config['firstTime'] == 1 || self.lastGame['time'] != tempLast){
            self.lastGame['time'] = tempLast;
        }


    });
};
```

### Update

> if I set `self.config['time'] = "whatever"`, `this.config['time']` remains unchanged.

Yes. That's because `this` refers to the `request` function local scope, rather than the `loadProfile` scope you want to refer to. That is why you should be using the `self` reference, rather than `this`. `self` kept a reference to `this` in the context of `loadProfile`. Then, `this` changed when you entered the `request` callback's context.

Comment: How could `let` help in this case?

Comment: I see. Adding var self = this; didn't work however. I tried console.log(this) and found out that request actually populates "this" with its own data. Might it be that this is the problem?

Comment: Scratch that. It works, but partly. This is what I was talking about at the end of my question. If I pass this to the function, any modifications I make will not be reflected to the class variables. What I mean is, if I set self.config['time'] = "whatever", this.config['time'] remains unchanged.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you but I'm not sure I understand. What I'm trying to do is read( I've now got this part) and alter(which is what I can't understand) the values of the variables of the class itself. I tried adding this.config['time'] = self.config['time'] after the request block but it didn't work as request is asynchronous. (I know config['time'] doesn't exist, I didn't notice it when I made the last comment so I'm just going through with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Inside request you have different scope. **This** inside request function is probably instance of request object. You could try something like:

```
testClass.prototype.loadProfile = function(url){
    var self = this;

    request(url,function(error,response,body){
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        matchTable = $('div[class=test]').children();
        tempLast = matchTable.first().html();

        if(self.config['firstTime'] == 1 || self.lastGame['time'] != tempLast){
            self.lastGame['time'] = tempLast;
        }


    });
};
```